# While controller is running infinite loop

Tags: jmeter

On a http response for a http request I am checking a particular field from one status to another status using a while controller. But the while controller is not breaking the loop even after the condition is satisfied.

```
{
    "data": {
        "uri": null,
        "taskId": "f5b6aaf3-8b14-49ba-a495-788eef5c523b",
        "taskStatus": "Ongoing"
    },
    "apiUrl": "http:\/\/.int:8081\/release01-nightly-api\/\/2192_IND_1_40",
    "statusCode": "102"
}
```

So the above response  `"taskStatus": "Ongoing"` which will be `"Successfull"` after some time may be `20-30 seconds` so I have used a while controller, which is not breaking even after the condition is satisfied.

Here below the details of while controller,
[image]
I am fetching the status using a JSON extractor
[image]
Execution snapshot,
[image]
What I am doing wrong here

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Few things configured wrongly, encountered with similar situation this is the solution we implement,

1. First `http request` with `json extractor` seems fine. [No changes needed]
2. Now in the while controller please do the changes `${__javaScript("${task_status}"!="Success" && parseInt(vars.get("statusCounter"))<=30)}`
3. Under the while controller start a `counter` with the following values

   `starting value`: `0`

   `increment`: `1`

   `exported variable name` : `statusCounter`  [give this name according to your choice]
4. Under the while controller put the same `http request` and add a json extractor similar to `step 1`.
5. Under this request add a beanshell assertion and following code,

**Code Block for the assertion:**

```
try {
    if (vars.get("task_status").equals("Success")) {
        Failure = true;
        FailureMessage = "Workflow Status is not changed : " + vars.get("task_status_Upd");
        SampleResult.setStartNextThreadLoop(true);
    }

    if (vars.get("statusCounter") == 30) {
        Failure = true;
        FailureMessage = "RequestTimeOut";
        SampleResult.setStartNextThreadLoop(true);
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
    log.info("Error in beanshell", ex);
    throw ex;
}
```

Comment: Also, the while controller was running in infinite because of the condition were not set correctly, please try to avoid that further.
reference: https://dzone.com/articles/using-the-while-controller-in-jmeter

Comment: `task_status_Upd` is the inner json extractor value

Comment: Simply wow, thank you so much. It is working fine

Answer (score 1):

Your expression is wrong, change it to:

```
${__groovy((!vars.get('task_status').equals('Success') && (vars.get('__jm__While Controller__idx') as int ) < 30),)}
```

no other changes are required.

Going forward use [Debug Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) to evaluate your expressions

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: Yeah you can try Dmitri's one as well, it seems more simpler way